# Tailwind with vite.js unwanted page reload

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

I am trying to setup Vite JS for my development of my Wordpress Theme. For this theme I want to use Tailwind 3.

The problem I have is that the page is reloaded (Browser refresh) when I change html-classes in my php-files for tailwind to compile.

For example:
If I change the classes in my header.php

```
<h1 class="text-4xl font-bold underline">Testar</h1>
```

The browser will reload the page. I want HMR.
The console output is this:

> 8:32:22 AM [vite] page reload header.php (x6)

My style changes in my app.scss is working with HMR. It instantly updates the page with the new compiled style.
I know that this line in **tailwind.config.js**, is the one that gives me the unwanted page reload:

```
"./*.php",
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

---

These are my files:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./*.php",
    //"./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
// vite.config.js
export default ({ command }) => ({
    base: command === 'serve' ? '' : '/build/',
    publicDir: 'fake_dir_so_nothing_gets_copied',
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        outDir: 'public/build',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        },
    },
});
```

**app.js**

```
import '../scss/app.scss';
import '../scss/tailwind.scss';
import './modules/test.js';
```

**tailwind.scss**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**In the footer i have this to get HMR**

```
<?php if (IS_PRODUCTION) : ?>
<!-- .... -->
<?php else: ?>
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/resources/js/app.js"></script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Do you have any idea of how I can solve this? How I can get to the point where I directly see the tailwind style updates on my page without browser reload?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work you would have to create a Vite plugin which handles that. Second option is to use frontend like React, Vue, ...